# Cannot read properties of null (reading ‘data’)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

[This is what the error looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQAfk.jpg)

I tried to run a command on my discord bot (I have a language system for it and that’s from where i think the error came from), then my bot crashed then sent that error message in console

I thought it would work like it normally does but the bot just continues to crash everytime i run that command.

The part where the error came from according to console:

```
  const guild_settings = require('../database/models/guild-settings.js');
    const findLang = await guild_settings.findOne({ guild: interaction.guild.id });
    const lang = require(`../langs/${findLang.data.language || "en"}.js`);
```

Comment: Can you add the `guild_settings` schema as well?

Comment: well, it's telling you that findLang is null.  this is likely due to the findOne failing.  you don't catch on this, but continue, assuming it was successful.  Print out findLang in between the findOne and require and you'll see it's null.